# External Template for Column ClientTemplate

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have an issue on having an external template inside Column ClientTemplate

```
.Columns(col =>
    {        
        col.Bound(c => c.ID);
        col.Bound(c => c.Name).Width(100);      
        col.Bound(c => c.StatusID)
            .Title("Action")
            .ClientTemplate("#=_actionTemplate(data)#")
            .Width(100);
    })

    <script id="tmplAction" type="text/x-kendo-template">
        @(Html.Kendo().Button().Name("btnTest_#=ID#")
          .Content("Test")
          .ToClientTemplate())
    </script>

    <script>
        var _actionTemplate = kendo.template($('#tmplAction').html());
    </script>
```

Even though it is called and rendered inside the grid column, kendo script is not executed therefore the only rendered element is a basic Button and not Kendo Button

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Copied from your code :

```
.ClientTemplate("#= fnactionTemplate(data)#")
```

And declare that function like:

```
 function fnactionTemplate(data){
   // External logic goes here....
   return $('#tmplAction').html();
 }
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work. might work if pure jQuery but this is Kendo Telerik